# Can't figure out a linear equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am sorry, this is my first time here. I don't know if I put the question correctly.

Anyways, I have a simple question on me, middle school. Well, I am 14 meh. I am not being able to solve it. I would like it if someone could help me in it. Using Algebra and Linear Equations.. No AP or anything, we haven't studied it yet.

$\sqrt{x/y}$ + $\sqrt{y/x} = 10/3$
Find xy

Comment: Not a linear equation.  Because there is a square root sign that you want to go away, try squaring both sides as a first step.  What happens?

Comment: I tried. Couldn't get the answer though

Comment: (x^2+y^2)9/82=xy is what u get after manipulation. there must be one more equation, coz there are two unknowns

Comment: Try multiplying through by $\sqrt{x/y}$ first.  (Then square both sides.)

Comment: We cannot determine $xy$, because if we multiply each of $x$ and $y$  by $k\ne \pm 1$, we don't change your square-rooted expressions but we change $xy$.

Comment: @ketan, note that there is "sort of" only one unknown $z=\sqrt{x/y}$, because the equation is then $z+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{10}{3}$.

Comment: My guess is that the question has a typo, and they want you to find $x/y$, not $xy$. David's answer shows you how to do this.

Comment: I think youre right. I got this question frrom a book. The answer was given 9. I guess it was a typo after all. I hope it isnt an offence to post a wrong question?

Answer (score 2):

If you square both sides you get
$$\frac{x}{y}+2\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}+\frac{y}{x}=\frac{100}{9}\ ,$$
that is,
$$\frac{x}{y}+2+\frac{y}{x}=\frac{100}{9}$$
or
$$\frac{x}{y}-\frac{82}{9}+\frac{y}{x}=0\ .$$
Multiply both sides by $x/y$ to get
$$\Bigl(\frac{x}{y}\Bigr)^2-\frac{82}{9}\Bigl(\frac{x}{y}\Bigr)+1=0\ .$$
If you have studied quadratics you can now treat $x/y$ as a single variable to find two possible values
$$\frac{x}{y}=\cdots$$
Can you finish this?

However this will not give you a value for $x$ and $y$ separately, or for $xy$.  I don't think it is actually possible to answer the question you have been asked.

Comment: Thank you. I guess it's a wrong question then

Comment: Yes, but maybe only a little bit wrong.  Have another look at the source and see if you were given any more information about $x$ and $y$.

Comment: nope i wasnt...

Comment: When you simplified $\sqrt{\dfrac xy}\sqrt{\dfrac yx}$ to $1$ you have made the assumption that $x/y$ and $y/x$ can't be both negative. But there's nothing in the *énoncé* that says that $x/y$ and $y/x$ aren't both negative AFAIK.

Comment: As it's a middle school problem I think we can reasonably assume that complex numbers are not involved.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a *linear* equation, rather, it is a *radical* equation. To solve it, first square both sides and simplify.
$$\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{y}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{y}{x}}=\dfrac{10}{3}$$
$$\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{y}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{y}{x}}\right)^2=\left(\dfrac{10}{3}\right)^2$$
$$\dfrac{x}{y}+2\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{y}}\sqrt{\dfrac{y}{x}}+\dfrac{y}{x}=\dfrac{100}{9}$$
$$\dfrac{x}{y}+2\sqrt{\dfrac{xy}{yx}}+\dfrac{y}{x}=\dfrac{100}{9}$$
$$\dfrac{x}{y}+2+\dfrac{y}{x}=\dfrac{100}{9}$$
$$\dfrac{x}{y}+\dfrac{y}{x}-\dfrac{100}{9}+2=0$$
$$\dfrac{x}{y}+\dfrac{y}{x}-\dfrac{100}{9}+\dfrac{18}{9}=0$$
$$\dfrac{x}{y}+\dfrac{y}{x}-\dfrac{82}{9}=0$$
Multiply both sides by $\dfrac{x}{y}$ and simplify. We will get a *quadratic equation* (an equation of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants), which we can solve for.
$$\dfrac{x}{y}\left(\dfrac{x}{y}+\dfrac{y}{x}-\dfrac{82}{9}\right)=\dfrac{x}{y}\left(0\right)$$
$$\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)^2-\dfrac{82}{9}\cdot\dfrac{x}{y}+1=0$$
Let $\dfrac{x}{y}=a$. This allows for easier calculation.
$$a^2-\dfrac{82}{9}a+1=0$$
Multiply by $9$ on both sides to get rid of the denominator in $\dfrac{82}{9}x$.
$$9a^2-82a+9=0$$
Use the quadratic formula. If you did not know, the quadratic formula states:

> For any equation $ax^2+bx + c=0$ ($a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants), its roots are:
>   $$x=\dfrac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

$$a=\dfrac{-(-82)\pm\sqrt{(-82)^2-4(9)(9)}}{2(9)}$$
$$a=\dfrac{82\pm\sqrt{6724-324}}{18}$$
$$a=\dfrac{82\pm\sqrt{6400}}{18}$$
$$a=\dfrac{82\pm80}{18}$$
$$a=\dfrac{41\pm40}{9}$$
$$a=\dfrac{1}{9}, \ 9$$
$$\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{1}{9}, \ 9$$
Now, we will check for extraneous roots. Extraneous roots can be brought into the solution by squaring the square root. These answers are incorrect. Let's start with $\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{1}{9}$
$$\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{9}}+\sqrt{9}=\dfrac{10}{3}$$
$$\dfrac{1}{3}+3=\dfrac{10}{3}$$
$$\dfrac{10}{3}=\dfrac{10}{3}$$
$$\text{True.}$$
Now for $x=9$:
$$\sqrt{9}+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{9}}=\dfrac{10}{3}$$
$$3+\dfrac{1}{3}=\dfrac{10}{3}$$
$$\dfrac{10}{3}=\dfrac{10}{3}$$
$$\text{True.}$$
So:
$$\displaystyle \boxed{\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{1}{9}, \ 9}$$
**Everything from here on out are educated guesses.**
I do not think you can solve for $xy$. My logic may be wrong, but know that I am just trying to help.
We know that:
$$\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{1}{9}, \ 9$$
This can be rewritten as:
$$\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{1}{9}, \ \dfrac{9}{1}$$
This splits the equality into two cases.
**Case 1:** $\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{1}{9}$
$$\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{1}{9}$$
$$x=1$$
$$y=9$$
**Case 2:** $\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{9}{1}$
$$\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{9}{1}$$
$$x=9$$
$$y=1$$
You can see that in each of the solutions $x=1, \ y=9$ and $x=9, \ y=1$, $\boxed{xy=9}$. **But we must not forget** that there are the sets where $x=2, \ y=18$, $x=18, \ y=2$, $x=3, \ y=27$, $x=27, \ y=3$, etc. And that is just for whole numbers. What about decimals? There are an infinite number of solutions. So finding $xy$ is impossible.
Hopefully you were looking for $\dfrac{x}{y}$. Then, the solution is:
$$\displaystyle \boxed{\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{1}{9}, \ 9}$$
But if you really need to find the value of $xy$, then there are an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: From what I had solved it, x/y came to be equal to 9. Following David's Answer. How is your answer 1/9

Comment: @Bone $\dfrac{41\pm40}{9}=\dfrac{41+40}{9}, \ \dfrac{41-40}{9}$. Hopefully you knew that...

Comment: meh... oh well..

Comment: @Bone I added how you cannot solve for $xy$.

Comment: When you simplified $\sqrt{\dfrac xy}\sqrt{\dfrac yx}$ to $1$ you have made the explicit assumption that $x/y$ and $y/x$ can't be both negative. But there's nothing in the *énoncé* that says that $x/y$ and $y/x$ aren't both negative AFAIK.

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع That is why I plugged in the values of $\dfrac{x}{y}$ into the original equation; to make sure if it will give me the correct output. If I had an answer of $\dfrac{x}{y}=-\dfrac{1}{9}$, I would reject it, because $\sqrt{-\dfrac{1}{9}}$ does not exist

Comment: @JChau I'm assuming you deal only with the real numbers system, the problem is that the OP doesn't mention whether we should look for solutions in $\Bbb C$ or in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع Considering he is in middle school and he is 14, I think we can guess that he just wants $x, \ y \in \mathbb R$. Complex numbers are a very difficult topic, and I now hesitate to answer these questions on MSE, as I have not officially learnt about them yet.

Comment: @JChau Anyway, you  did a great job at answering his question.